# elasticsearch match on every element in the nested collection

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform an elastic-search query that will return documents where "every" element of the nested collection has a match, not just one.
For example, I have a Driver object, with the List of cars, and each car has the color attribute.

Driver index:

```
   curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/driver' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "driver": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "car": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "color": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

And the following data: Driver John with green and red car, and Driver Bob with two green cars.

```
    curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/driver/_doc/1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "driver": {
        "name": "John",
        "car": [
            {
                "color": "red"
            },
            {
                "color": "green"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/driver/_doc/2' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
    "driver": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "car": [
            {
                "color": "green"
            },
            {
                "color": "green"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

I want to find the driver that has ONLY green cars (i.e. Bob).
I tried the following query, but it returns a driver that has at least one car that matches color:

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:9200/driver/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "driver",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "driver.car",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "driver.car.color": "green"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This query returns every driver that has at least one green car.  What is the fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `must_not` query explicitly ruling out `red`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "driver.car",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "driver.car.color": "green"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "driver.car",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "driver.car.color": {
                  "gt": "green"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

BTW you don't need the double nesting -- `drive.car` will work exactly the same as `driver` -> `driver.car`.

Comment: thank you for your response.  but what if I have many other colors but red, i.e. it is not practical for me to include every possible value in "must not".  
There is no way to tell elastic search to ensure EVERY element of collection equals GREEN?  i.e. AND condition not OR?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. But you could quickly check *before* indexing the document (in a language of your choice) whether that's the case and maybe create a top-level, non-nested field containing that value. Alternatively, you can take a look at Ingest Pipelines to do the *upon* indexing, directly in ES.

Comment: thank you, I actually ended up doing what u suggesting, calculating value before indexing :). Thanks again.